# Cómo poner un like="%busqueda %" a un INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando hacer un buscador pero no tengo una tabla si no una consulta hecha por INNER JOIN, entonces quiero saber cómo agrego el `like="%%"` para que me pueda buscar entre los campos de la consulta hecha en el inner.

La consulta es la siguiente.

```
select distinct(r.Id_Estudiante), e.Nombres, e.grado
from relacion r
inner join estudiantes e on e.Id_Estudiante = r.Id_Estudiante
```

Y por hay derecho que la consulta me quede ordenada de manera ascendente por el nombre.

Comment: el like es una clausula del where, no del join. los joins son perfectos, con campos identicos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando en internet y preguntando, encontré la respuesta.

La variable `$busqueda` la puse para que vean que pueden ingresar una variable y cuando definan la variable poner las condiciones que necesitan.

Aquí el código que me funcionó.

```
select distinct(r.Estudiante), e.Nombres, e.grado
from relacion r
inner join estudiantes e on e.Estudiante = r.Estudiante order by e.Nombres

where e.Nombres like '%busqueda%'
OR e.Grado like '%".$busqueda."%'
OR r.Estudiante like '%".$busqueda."%';";
```

Pongo los 3 campos `Id_Estudiante`, `Nombres` y `Grado` por si desean buscar por cualquiera de los 3 campos.

Comment: en realidad.. no es del todo correcto. Salvo para nombre, grado deberia ser un string normalizado (en realidad un id que apunte a una tabla de grados posibles, no hay cualquier grado), entonces en ese caso la seleccion es sobre los grados posibles. Y id, deberia ser un numero valido, con lo cual tampoco iria en un like, si no en una seleccion directa de los numeros posibles (es mas, ni siquiera se deberia buscar por eso).

Answer (score 0):

Sé que este post es bastante viejo, pero igual, cualquiera que ande buscando algo relacionado tal vez le pueda servir este código.

Hice un consulta sencillita en un procedimiento almacenado en SQL SERVER.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Buscar]
@Nombre varchar(50)

AS

SET @Nombre=CONCAT('%', @Nombre, '%')

SELECT t1.IDPRODUCTO, t1.NOMBRE, t1.PRECIO, t2.MARCA, t3.CATEGORIA
FROM PRODUCTO t1
INNER JOIN MARCA t2 ON t1.IDMARCA = t2.IDMARCA
INNER JOIN CATEGORIA t3 ON t1.IDCATEGORIA = t3.IDCATEGORIA
WHERE t1.NOMBRE LIKE @Nombre

RETURN  0
```

Lo que hace la consulta es mostrar los campos idProducto, Nombre y Precio de la tabla PRODUCTO, el campo Marca de la tabla MARCA y el campo Categoria de la tabla CATEGORIA.

Para la búsqueda con la cláusula LIKE lo que hice fue concatenar la variable @Nombre y sólo se lo pasé al WHERE y ya.

Es una consulta sencillita, espero ayudar a personas sin experiencia como es mi caso.

Saludos cordiales a todos.

Comment: Nadamas considera que el OP usa MySQL y no SQL Server

Comment: Es cierto, pero creo que tranquilamente podría adaptarlo a sus necesidades, en este caso a MYSQL.